# Sorting nested list

Tags: python, maya

Im trying to sort my list which contains of 3 nested lists: paths, file names and finally file creation time. So I want to sort them to be able to get the latest files.

So Ive seen people been using lambda for this, but I dont feel comfortable using those and kind of dont get how to the sorting with that works.

I think the best way is just to switch the list components, but this does not work:

```
class FILE:
    PATH = 0
    NAME = 1
    DATE = 2

mayaFiles = [[],[],[]]
mayaFiles[FILE.DATE] = [0,56,3,12,7,35,16]

doSwitch = True
while (doSwitch):
    for ma in range(0, len(mayaFiles[FILE.DATE])-1):
        doSwitch = False
        doSwitch = mayaFiles[FILE.DATE][ma] > mayaFiles[FILE.DATE][ma+1]
        hi = mayaFiles[FILE.DATE][ma]
        lo = mayaFiles[FILE.DATE][ma+1]
        if doSwitch:
            mayaFiles[FILE.DATE][ma] = lo
            mayaFiles[FILE.DATE][ma+1] = hi
        else:
            break

print mayaFiles[FILE.DATE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these lists are already aligned, you'll have a much easier time by combing the there separate lists into a list of tuples arranged by your sort order.   the `namedtuple` construct in the `collections` module is great for this sort of thing.  I'm assuming you can get your data into three lists: `paths`, `dates` and `names`.  I'm supplying some dummy data here so you can see what I'm assuming.

```
names = "a.ma", "b.ma", "c.ma", "d.ma"
paths = "c:/test", "c/test", "c:/other", "d:/extra"
dates = "17-01-01", "16-01-01", "17-02-01", "17-06-30"

# this creates a namedtuple, which is a 
# mini-class with named fields that otherwise
# works like a tuple

from collections import namedtuple
record = namedtuple("filerecord", "date name path")

# in real use this should be a list comp
# but this is easier to read:

records = []    
for date, name, path in zip(dates, names, paths):
    records.append(record(date, name, path))

records.sort(reverse=True)
for item in records: 
    print item

# filerecord(date='17-06-30', name='d.ma', path='d:/extra')
# filerecord(date='17-02-01', name='c.ma', path='c:/other')
# filerecord(date='17-01-01', name='a.ma', path='c:/test')
# filerecord(date='16-01-01', name='b.ma', path='c/test')
```

You could sort on other fields using the 'key' argument to `sort()`:

```
records.sort(key=lambda k: k.name)
for item in records: 
    print item

# filerecord(date='17-01-01', name='a.ma', path='c:/test')
# filerecord(date='16-01-01', name='b.ma', path='c/test')
# filerecord(date='17-02-01', name='c.ma', path='c:/other')
# filerecord(date='17-06-30', name='d.ma', path='d:/extra')
```